# Errors while linking in Qt5 with poppler

Tags: c++, linux, qt5, poppler

> /usr/lib/libpoppler.so.50: undefined reference to `std::__throw_out_of_range_fmt(char const*, ...)@GLIBCXX_3.4.20'
>   Makefile:156: recipe for target 'DocViewer' failed
>   /usr/lib/libsystemd.so.0: undefined reference to`lzma_stream_decoder@XZ_5.0'
>   /usr/lib/libQt5Core.so: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length@CXXABI_1.3.8'
>   /usr/lib/libsystemd.so.0: undefined reference to`lzma_end@XZ_5.0'
>   /usr/lib/libsystemd.so.0: undefined reference to `lzma_code@XZ_5.0'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make: *** [DocViewer] Error 1
>   20:53:35: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.

I get the errors mentioned above while compiling a program using `poppler` in `Qt5`.

Below is my project file, should in change something?

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = DocViewer
TEMPLATE = app

INCLUDEPATH  += /usr/include/poppler/qt5
LIBS         += -L/usr/lib -lpoppler-qt5

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

Comment: Looks like `-llzma` is also missing.

Comment: `LIBS         += -L/usr/lib -lpoppler-qt5 -llzma`
something like this?

Comment: Yes. But there's still that other linker error about `std::__throw_out_of_range_fmt(char const*, ...)@GLIBCXX_3.4.20`.

Comment: can it have something to do with the `glibc` version installed on my system.

Comment: Could well be an issue, yes. Try to install the actual GCC 4.9.2.

Answer (score 0):

For the "__cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length@CXXABI_1.3.8" error in libicu, it looks like the problem is an incompatible icu build (softfp vs hardfp).

I had the same error, which I solved by downloading a rebuilt ICU (to avoid rebuilding it myself).

- Download the "POT" binaries from
  http://thebugfreeblog.blogspot.fr/2016/12/binaries-for-pot-550-beta1-on-qt-580.html.
- lrzuntar the file
- tar xf qtdeps.tar
- on the device, move away libicu* (in my case with raspbian it was in usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf), and transfer the libicu* from qtdeps over there
- on the device, move away the "unicode" include dir (with raspbian it was in /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/unicode), and copy the unicode include dir from qtdeps over there.
- re-sync from the device to your sysroot using rsync
- reconfigure and rebuilt qtbase (after removing the .o files under qtbase/src/corelib that contain "icu" in the name - or rebuild Qt from scratch)